Regex - Does not contain '<' &' >'Characters
I need a regex to match if anywhere in a sentence there is either < or >.
If either < or > are in the string then it must return true.
If both < and > are in the string in this order then it must return false.
example :- I am using '<'JAVA'>' regex.
If both > and < are in the string in this order then it must return true.
example :- I am using >JAVA< regex.
Thanks for the help.

You seem to be contradicting yourself. First you say that if both characters are in the string it should be false, then you say if both are in the string it should return true. Which is it?

Does the order matter? So <...> returns  false, but >...< returns true? What if it has <foo>bar<baz> That has both <foo> and >bar<.

The general solution is to use a negative lookahead to match the pattern that should return false. So (?!.*<.*>) returns false for <...>

Form the expression "(contains at least one < but no >) or (contains at least one > but no <)".

@YvesDaoust right if < comes thes > should not come . If > comes then < should be fine

"in this pattern" should be "in this order".

Your question is ambiguous regarding the order. You should fix that.

Use [<>] to match either < or >. Use the negative lookahead (?!.*<.*>) to disallow both of them in this order.
Then combine them:
^(?!.*<.*>).*[<>]

DEMO

++, but (<|>) could be [<>] for better clarity & performance.

Thanks, sometimes you get tunnel vision :)
